# how to know if disks are from Jbod or integral as part of the HW machine

Tags: linux, devices, disk, block-device, dmidecode

In some cases when we are not near the HW Linux machine, we are only able to see disks as the following:

```
/dev/sdd                  20511312   199536  20295392   1% /grd/sdd
/dev/sdb                  20511312   487852  20007076   3% /grd/sdb
/dev/sde                  20511312    91572  20403356   1% /grd/sde
/dev/sdf                  20511312    45192  20449736   1% /grd/sdf
```

but do not get the info if the disks are in the HW machine or come from an external JBOD.

How to know where are the disks located? 
Maybe by `dmidecode` or something else?

Comment: How is the external storage connected?

Comment: "udevadm info" maybe useful.

Comment: @Jaroslav Kucera not have info about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try hdparm -i {device}, like:

```
# hdparm -i /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

 Model=SAMSUNG MZ7TD512HAGM-000L1, FwRev=DXT05L0Q, 
SerialNo=S151NYADA01701
 Config={ Fixed }
 RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=0, SectSize=0, ECCbytes=0
 BuffType=unknown, BuffSize=unknown, MaxMultSect=16, MultSect=16
 CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=1000215216
 IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
 PIO modes:  pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
 DMA modes:  mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 
 UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
 AdvancedPM=no WriteCache=enabled
 Drive conforms to: unknown:  ATA/ATAPI-2,3,4,5,6,7

 * signifies the current active mode
```

The above is correct output for standard disk drive. I believe it should fail for virtual disks, like JBOD or RAID. Then it displays something like:

```
# hdparm -i /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument
```

However if your local disks are also of RAID type provided by some HW controller, the hdparm isn't much usefull. Then you may try the udevadm:

```
udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)
```

The output of it is quite long, so I won't paste it here all, but there is enough information to distinguish types of sdX devices on your node, when you compare outputs.